What does "desk_rt_ipc_error" mean in AnyDesk?
Ever since this morning, when I try to connect to one of my servers, then I get an error popup that says:

Session ended


The session has ended unexpectedly.


Status: desk_rt_ipc_error



What does this error mean? What is causing it?
The Anydesk to this server was working perfectly find without any issues a few hours ago (last night)

There's this small (i) next to the error. Have you clicked it?

@LPChip Yes. I have clicked on it, but nothing happens. It doesn't do anything.

What if you hover it?

@LPChip Ah. If I hover long enough, then a link appears: https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/status-desk_rt_ipc_error

My Solution:
The solution for me ended up being that I had to physically go to the server and restart it. After the server was restarted, I was able to finally connect to it again via AnyDesk.

For those which the above doesn't work. I found this link that says the following:
Description:
This error typically occurs when an external application, such as the operating system or a security tool, terminates the AnyDesk session. The underlying causes and potential solutions may differ depending on the operating system.
If you encounter this message while attempting to connect to a Windows device, it's highly likely that a security solution installed on the device is responsible for disconnecting AnyDesk or other remote desktop connections. A typical cause of this issue is anti-ransomware security features.
On the other hand, if you encounter this error while connecting to a Linux device, it may be because of an unsupported display server.
Potential other solutions:
Windows:
Whitelist AnyDesk or disable anti-ransomware features on the device.
Reinstall AnyDesk if the security solution blocks or quarantines the application.
Linux:
Ensure that both the login manager and the system are using Xorg to avoid unsupported display server issues.
Make sure that the DNS resolver resolves AnyDesk URL addresses correctly. See Firewall.
